# Use c++ gslice to hide specific elements in valarray<int>

Tags: c++, time-complexity, slice, indices, valarray

I want to hide multiple elements in a `valarray<int>` which has consecutive integers starting from 0. For example, from `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` to `{0, 2, 3, 5}`. I have found that I can use `indirect array` to specify elements indices with `valarray<size_t>`. However, I don't know how to generate `valarray<size_t>` with indices I want in `O(1)` complexity. `O(1)` complexity or at most `O(logn)` complexity is very important to me. So, I think `gslice` may be able to solve the problem, but I still can't figure out how to implement it.

Note: I use `c++11`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `O(1)`.Wouldn't you need to make at least a single pass over the original `valarry` to generate a new one?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/gslice, it says `gslice` in `valarray` has constant complexity.

Comment: The only mention of constant complexity on that page is for `start`, `size` and `stride`, not for the constructor of `gslice`.

Comment: But I have tested `gslice` with very large `valarray`, and it always shows 0ms.

Comment: Actual run-time is not the same thing as algorithmic complexity. Run the program with increasing sizes of `valarray`s and plot the corresponding time taken. The change in the time taken is what you need to look at. Otherwise, the constant factors in the complexity bounds will completely mess up your analysis.

Comment: I just tested `gslice` on `valarray<int>` with sizes differ from 9, 90, 900, ..., 90000000. They all showed 0 nanoseconds. I think gslice is really constant in complexity. The gslice I used has 3 as start index, {19, 4, 1} as sizes, {2, 4, 3} as strides.

Comment: Increase your `gslice` sizes much more. Make them proportional to the sizes of the valarrys from which you're constructing them, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Now the `strides` are all {2, 4, 3}, and the start indices are all 3. `valarray` pairs to gslice with same size of `sizes` (filled with random numbers varied from 0 to `the size`). The results are:
sizes 9 <-> 0 nanoseconds, 
sizes 90 <-> 0 nanoseconds, 
sizes 900 <-> 0 nanoseconds, 
sizes 9000 <-> 0 nanoseconds, 
sizes 90000 <-> 1000000 nanoseconds, 
sizes 900000 <-> 9996000 nanoseconds, 
sizes 9000000 <-> 59965000 nanoseconds.

Comment: Yeah, looks at least linear, i.e. `O(n)` to me.

Comment: What if it's possible to hide specific indices with gslice of small sizes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Sure, you could `gslice` with small sizes. It would still be `O(n)` though, but it wouldn't matter because `n` is small.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I meant.